# How to remove defaut icon/title from top of main layout in Android?

Tags: java, android

Check out this picture:

[WhoKnew title and WK? Icon http://puu.sh/5Ejo5.png](http://puu.sh/5Ejo5.png)

See the icon and title there? How do I go about removing that?

I'm not using any of the drag and drop or xml editing at all in eclipse for this project, because I have to dynamically create an arbitrary amount of buttons/text, and whatnot.

Basically, I've been going about it by doing something like this..

```
public createMainMenu(){
    //make layout
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
    layout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);

    //make/add text to layout
    menuText.setText("Who Knew?");
    menuText.setId(20001);
    menuText.setTextSize(36);
    menuText.setTextColor(textColor);
    layout.addView(menuText);

    //make a scrollview, then add the layout to the scrollview
    ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(this);
    sc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    sc.setFillViewport(true);
    sc.addView(layout);

    //set content view to the scrollview
    setContentView(sc);

}
```

Hopefully, I'm on the right track here on how I should be going about this. The app I have is working fine, I just need to get rid of that icon/title bar, if possible. I guess it's not a gamebreaker, but it's a bit annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this in your java class

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Although now there's a bit of a flash of the title bar before the app starts. Anything I can do to get around that?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: Although it did technically fix the problem, this changed a LOT in my app (visually), assuming "Light" is a different theme than I'm using. Any other solution? Sorry for being so ignorant on the topic. Learning as I go

Comment: Oh, yeah, it depends on what theme you're using. Do you know what you're using? Try replacing Light with Dark.

Comment: It's basically telling me that Dark doesn't exist. Is there a list of themes somewhere on the net? I could just go through them one by one until I find out which I'm using. (It's whatever is default)

Comment: err, my bad. I think it's 'Black', not 'Dark'.

Comment: Nope. Still weird looking. It basically smooths/rounds out all of my buttons and makes my rating icons strange looking.